# Graph - Dijkstra's algorithm - Tile-based map - Is there "blocking" term in graph?

Tags: math, graph-theory, dijkstra

Let's suppose there is tile-based map. Each tile(vertex) has edges to 8 neighbour tiles. On one of these tiles, there is a wall(which is completly blocking).

From mathematical point of view, does it mean that vertex(on which there is a wall):

1. Does not exists?
2. There are no edges to this vertex?
3. Vertex is just blocking - is there this term in graph teory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically this is normally modeled as (1) the node not existing. In an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm, however, usually there is a function that maps a node to its sequence of neighbors that the algorithm uses to traverse the graph. That function would simply not return any "blocking" neighbors, which could be interpreted as either (1) the node not existing or (2) no edges being incident to the "blocking" node. How you choose to interpret it doesn't really matter—the implementation ends up the same.